# How to add your data-properties (meta data) to PDF (iTextSharp)

Tags: c#, itext

I convert the file to PDF using iTextSharp
Creating a new Document and inserting an image into it. How can I transfer width and height of a image to a new pdf? (because the image is compressed)
In the new Document, you can pass the title, keywords, etc. But if you need somewhere to store the old width and height (since the image is compressed), and when reading the PDF to the size of the old pictures. Each page has its own data.

Answer (score 0):

This solution helped. Info contains metadata.

```
using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs))
  {
    PdfDictionary info = writer.Info;
    PdfName newData = new PdfName($"NewData");
    info.Put(newData, new PdfString("any string data"));
   }
```

Comment: How would you categorize your custom data? ISO 32000-1 states *"Although conforming readers may store custom metadata in the document information dictionary, they may not store private content or structural information there. Such information shall be stored in the document catalogue instead (see 7.7.2, “Document Catalog”)."*